# What can be changed by user on web? (eg. $_SESSION, JS code)

Tags: javascript, php, security

I would like to know what can and what can not be changed by user related to **Web Development**.
Mainly if **users** can **change variables in $_SESSION**.
But it would be nice to know if some techniques that seem secure are actually not.
Another example would be user changing code in JS Classes etc.

I am sorry if this question seems too trivial to someone. Studied Web Development for 2 years and would like to learn something new.

Here is a example of code where I am not sure if user can change his $_SESSION['group']

```
    public function login() {
          if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {
              if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
                // Fetching user data
                  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT Password FROM TB_Users WHERE Username = ?');
                  $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
                  $user = $stmt->fetch();
                //-----------------------
                // Password Verification 
                  if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['Password'])) {
                //-----------------------
                // Fetching Group of user so it can be used later to fetch Permissions
                    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT TB_userGroups_ID FROM TB_Users WHERE Username = ?');
                    $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
                    $UserGroup = $stmt->fetch();
                    $_SESSION['group'] = $UserGroup['TB_userGroups_ID'];
                //-----------------------
                // Sending user back from Login page to Main/Index page
                    header("Location: ../index.php");
                    exit();
                //-----------------------
                  }
              }
          }
```

Many thanks for any help or redirection to sources.

Comment: In fact, everything you send to the user/client can be changed by the user/client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `user` you mean visitors to the website and not developers (just making sure), then no they cannot unilaterally change anything in `$_SESSION` since those values only exist on the server. The user only has a cookie on their end that the server uses to recognize which collection of `$_SESSION` variables belong to them. The developer is responsible for making sure that what goes into the `$_SESSION` is controlled. In the example you have here, the only way `$_SESSION` gets changed is based on what is retrieved from the database, so assuming that content is safe, then it is protected.

My only recommendation would be to get rid of your `isset($_POST['var'])` stuff and replace it with `filter_input()`. You can use this to retrieve values from `$_POST` and also sanitize them. When called, you can expect `null` or `false` for missing or invalid content, so it's a little easier to control validation vs empty values. Sample:

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Full docs on that here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Be sure to familiarize yourself with the filter flags. `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` for instance is not a great one for passwords.

Some other things to consider:

- Make sure your session cookies are flagged with HTTPOnly and Secure and if on PHP7+ also set SameSite flag to strict. HTTPOnly prevents javascript from being able to modify the cookie. These settings are in `php.ini`.
- Make sure your users are protected from XSS where someone could access their session through malicious code injected into your site (or perhaps a completely external site). These headers can be set in an `.htaccess` or in a host/vhost configuration file.
- Ensure that your encryption policy for passwords meets basic requirements including secure encryption methods and salts. In general you shouldn't have to retrieve a password from the database; you should be able to salt and encrypt the provided password one way and change your query to simply count the number of rows matching username and the encrypted password. This way the secured password in the database never exists on the web server (even in memory).